# How to use ":g/regex/d_" without losing current cursor position

Tags: vim

In Vim, if you run

```
:g/some_word/d_
```

all lines containing "some_word" are removed and the cursor automatically jumps to the place of last deletion. I want the cursor to stay where it was before the operation. How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't make the cursor *stay* but you can make it *go back* to where it was:

```
:g/some_word/d_|norm ''
```

Comment: Two minor improvement to your answer I'd like to suggest: using backticks instead of single-quotes will also restore the cursor to the right column. Using `norm!` instead of `norm` will avoid issues if something was remapped for one reason or another.

Answer (score 3):

The answer by romainl is a good one, and it should do the trick without any additional fuss.

If this is a common problem, and you'd rather not add the additional `norm! ''` at the end (or type the key sequence when you're done), you could encapsulate it in a command:

```
command! -nargs=* G call s:G(<q-args>)

function! s:G(args)
  let saved_position = winsaveview()
  exe 'g'.a:args
  call winrestview(saved_position)
endfunction
```

The `:G` command will invoke the `s:G` function with all of its arguments, which saves the position, runs the normal `g` with these exact arguments, and then restores it. So you'd do `:G/some_word/d_` and it would run the command and restore the cursor in the line/column where it started.

Obviously, this only makes sense if you use it often enough and you don't often work on bare Vims (like on remote servers and such). Otherwise, it might be a better idea to try romainl's suggestion, or get used to typing in `''`. Your choice.

Also, if the current position happens to be *after* some of these lines, the cursor might end up in an unexpected place. For example, if your cursor is on line 7 and the command deletes line 3, then you'll be back at line 7, but all the text will have shifted up one line, so you'll be in the "wrong" place. You could probably play around with this function and compensate for the change, but it'll get pretty complicated pretty fast, so I wouldn't recommend it :)

Comment: though romainl's answer is what fits me well, your way is good to keep in mind, thank you

Answer (score 1):

The [anwolib plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3800) provides a handy `:KeepView` command; you can apply this to any Ex command, so it's even more generic than the `:G` command suggested by @AndrewRadev:

```
:KeepView g/some_word/d_
```